# Vectorizing MATLAB function

Tags: matlab, sum, vectorization, bessel-functions

I have double summation over *m* = 1:*M* and *n* = 1:*N* for polar point with coordinates *rho*, *phi*, *z*:

[image: Double summ over m and n]

I have written vectorized notation of it:

```
N = 10;
M = 10;
n = 1:N;
m = 1:M;

rho = 1;
phi = 1;
z = 1;

summ =  cos (n*z)  * besselj(m'-1, n*rho) * cos(m*phi)';
```

Now I need to rewrite this function for accepting vectors (columns) of coordinates *rho*, *phi*, *z*. I tried arrayfun, cellfun, simple for loop - they work too slow for me. I know about "MATLAB array manipulation tips and tricks", but as MATLAB beginner I can't understand repmat and other functions.

Can anybody suggest vectorized solution?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the dimensions of each variable. I.e. `rho` is `1xA`, etc. and what dimensions you expect for the output. First of all, this helps us to help you and secondly, this helps you to help yourself as proper dimensions are the first thing to consider when using MATLAB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your code is already well vectorized (for `n` and `m`). If you want this function to also accept an array of `rho`/`phi`/`z` values, I suggest you simply process the values in a for-loop, as I doubt any further vectorization will bring significant improvements (plus the code will be harder to read).

Having said that, in the code below, I tried to vectorize the part where you compute the various components being multiplied `{row N} * { matrix N*M } * {col M} = {scalar}`, by making a single call to the BESSELJ and COS functions (I place each of the row/matrix/column in the third dimension). Their multiplication is still [done in a loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7265247/tensor-contraction-in-matlab-closed) (ARRAYFUN to be exact):

```
%# parameters
N = 10; M = 10;
n = 1:N; m = 1:M;

num = 50;
rho = 1:num; phi = 1:num; z = 1:num;

%# straightforward FOR-loop
tic
result1 = zeros(1,num);
for i=1:num
    result1(i) = cos(n*z(i)) * besselj(m'-1, n*rho(i)) * cos(m*phi(i))';
end
toc

%# vectorized computation of the components
tic
a = cos( bsxfun(@times, n, permute(z(:),[3 2 1])) );
b = besselj(m'-1, reshape(bsxfun(@times,n,rho(:))',[],1)');             %'
b = permute(reshape(b',[length(m) length(n) length(rho)]), [2 1 3]);    %'
c = cos( bsxfun(@times, m, permute(phi(:),[3 2 1])) );
result2 = arrayfun(@(i) a(:,:,i)*b(:,:,i)*c(:,:,i)', 1:num);            %'
toc

%# make sure the two results are the same
assert( isequal(result1,result2) )
```

I did another benchmark test using the [TIMEIT](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/18798) function (gives more fair timings). The result agrees with the previous:

```
0.0062407    # elapsed time (seconds) for the my solution
0.015677     # elapsed time (seconds) for the FOR-loop solution
```

Note that as you increase the size of the input vectors, the two methods will start to have similar timings (the FOR-loop even wins on some occasions)

Comment: Thank you very much. Your code works super fast. I'll keep this code snippet as an example for `bsxfun` and `permute`. I tried to replace arrayfun with for loop and I got extra 2-10 times faster code. It seems that `arrayfun` and `cellfun` are slower, than ordinary for-loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to create two matrices, say `m_` and `n_` so that by selecting element `i,j` of each matrix you get the desired index for both `m` and `n`.

Most MATLAB functions accept matrices and vectors and compute their results element by element. So to produce a double sum, you compute all elements of the sum in parallel by  `f(m_, n_)` and sum them.

In your case (note that the `.*` operator performs element-wise multiplication of matrices)

```
N = 10;
M = 10;
n = 1:N;
m = 1:M;

rho = 1;
phi = 1;
z = 1;

% N rows x M columns for each matrix
% n_ - all columns are identical
% m_ - all rows are identical
n_ = repmat(n', 1,  M);
m_ = repmat(m , N,  1);

element_nm =  cos (n_*z) .* besselj(m_-1, n_*rho) .* cos(m_*phi);
sum_all = sum( element_nm(:) );
```

Comment: Hello, nimrodm! Thank you for your answer. But it is not what I mean. I mean, that *rho*, *phi*, *z* will be vectors i.e. rho=0:4, phi=0:4, z=0:4. Your code does not accept vectors for these variables. It gives the same result as my code (for scalar values of *rho*, *phi* and *z*), but executes 620 times slower than mine. My variant means {row N} * { matrix N*M } * {col M} = {scalar}. That is why I did not use element-wise operators (such as .*).