# Calculating the covariance of a 1000 5x5 matrices in matlab

Tags: matlab

I have a 1000 5x5 matrices (**Xm**) like this:

[image]

Each $(x_ij)*m$ is a point estimate drawn from a distribution. I'd like to calculate the covariance `cov` of each $x*{ij}$, where i=1..n, and j=1..n in the direction of the red arrow.

For example the variance of $X_m$ is `var(X,0,3) which gives a 5x5 matrix of variances. Can I calculate the covariance in the same way?

**Attempt at answer**

So far I've done this:

```
for m=1:1000
Xm_new(m,:)=reshape(Xm(:,:,m)',25,1);
end

cov(Xm_new)
spy(Xm_new) gives me this unusual looking sparse matrix:
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at `cov` (`edit cov` in the command window) you might see why it doesn't support multi-dimensional arrays. It perform a transpose and a matrix multiplication of the input matrices: `xc' * xc`. Both operations don't support multi-dimensional arrays and I guess whoever wrote the function decided not to do the work to generalize it (it still might be good to contact the Mathworks however and [make a feature request](http://www.mathworks.com/support/service_requests/contact_support.do)).

In your case, if we take the basic code from `cov` and make a few assumptions, we can write a covariance function M-file the supports 3-D arrays:

```
function x = cov3d(x)
% Based on Matlab's cov, version 5.16.4.10

[m,n,p] = size(x);
if m == 1
    x = zeros(n,n,p,class(x));
else
    x = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m);
    for i = 1:p
        xi = x(:,:,i);
        x(:,:,i) = xi'*xi;
    end
    x = x/(m-1);
end
```

Note that this simple code assumes that `x` is a series of 2-D matrices stacked up along the third dimension. And the normalization flag is 0, the default in `cov`. It could be exapnded to multiple dimensions like `var` with a bit of work. In my timings, it's over 10 times faster than a function that calls `cov(x(:,:,i))` in a `for` loop.

Yes, I used a `for` loop. There may or may not be [faster ways to do this](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/25977-mtimesx-fast-matrix-multiply-with-multi-dimensional-support), but in this case `for` loops are going to be [faster than most schemes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6580656/matlab-how-to-vector-multiply-two-arrays-of-matrices), especially when the size of your array is not known a priori.

Comment: Ah very nice! Thank you! I am however looking for a 5x5 covariance matrix based on a 1000 observations (stacked ontop of each other in the 3rd dimension) of each variable x_ij. So for example Xm(1,1,:) are observations of the same variable, etc. Is this what this function is doing?

Comment: It's equivalent to calling the `cov` function 1000 times for a 5-by-5 input and storing the 5-by-5 output: `Xm_out(:,:,1)=cov(Xm(:,:,1))`, `Xm_out(:,:,2)=cov(Xm(:,:,2))`, ..., `Xm_out(:,:,999)=cov(Xm(:,:,999))`, `Xm_out(:,:,1000)=cov(Xm(:,:,1000))`.

Comment: Oh ah... I'm trying to find the covariance for each x_ij, i\ne=j, such that x12 is the covariance between the column vectors x1 and x2 going in the direction of the red arrow. Have I not asked the correct question?

Comment: X(1,1,:) are iid of x1 and X(1,2,:) are iid of x2. I'd like to create the 5x5 matrix of covariances Y where each entry y_ij, was the covariance between X(i,j,:). Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, now I am confused as to what you want. My answer is the direct analog to `var(X,0,3)` that you mentioned in your question. It sounds like you want to find the covariance of the 1-by-1-by-1000 (same as 1-by-1000 really) vector `X(i,j,:)`? As per the help for `cov`, `cov(x)` for vector `x` is equivalent to the variance, i.e., `var`.

Comment: Thanks, I'd like to find the covariance thus: `for i=1:5 for j=1:5 find covariance between X(i,j,:)and X(i,j,:) end end`. Does this make sense? The simple reason I don't use the for loop is because I'm told X(i,j,:) must be 2D.

Comment: Ok, let `v=rand(1,1,1000);` be your `X(i,j,:)` for `i=1,j=1`. Now, y1=cov(v)` gives the error "Inputs must be 2-D." So do this: `y1=cov(squeeze(v))`. However, this is equivalent to `y2=var(v,0,3)` (or simply `y2=var(v)` in this case). Or are you asking about `y3=cov(squeeze(v),squeeze(v))`? That's just equal to `[y2 y2;y2 y2]` as you're calculating the covariance of something with respect to itself. That's what the "covariance between `X(i,j,:)` and `X(i,j,:)`" means. It's a bit nonsensical. From how your data is stored and based on what you've asked, my code still makes the most sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

The answer below also works for a rectangular matrix `xi=x(:,:,i)`

```
function xy = cov3d(x)

[m,n,p] = size(x);
if m == 1
    x = zeros(n,n,p,class(x));
else
    xc = bsxfun(@minus,x,sum(x,1)/m);
    for i = 1:p
        xci = xc(:,:,i);
        xy(:,:,i) = xci'*xci;
    end
    xy = xy/(m-1);
end
```

My answer is very similar to horchler, however horchler's code does not work with rectangular matrices `xi` (whose dimensions are different from `xi'*xi` dimensions).