# Operating on a vector from 4D matrix in Matlab

Tags: matlab

I am trying to do an operation like the following for every pixels in an image:

[image: equation]

A is x*y*4 matrix, w is simply an 1x9 vector.

I have a matrix L which is 200x200x4x9.

The first two dimensions of L are (x,y) location of pixels. Each location has 4 different sub-pixel (the third dimension). Every sub-pixel has a vector m, which is the last dimension is the m in my equation.

I plan to get the result for the 1st sub-pixel for the whole image, that's what I tried:

```
A (:,:,1) = w * L (:, :, 1, :)  ====> Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.
A (:,:,1) = w * L (:, :, 1, :)' ====> Transpose on ND array is not defined.
A (:,:,1) = w * reshape (L (:, :, 1, :), 1, 9)' ===> To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
```

If I just print L (1,1,1,:) I get values of individual elements (does not look like a vector):

```
ans(:,:,1,1) = 0.8980
ans(:,:,1,2) = 0.8065
ans(:,:,1,3) = 0.8471
ans(:,:,1,4) = 0.7607
ans(:,:,1,5) = 0.7175
ans(:,:,1,6) = 0.9020
ans(:,:,1,7) = 0.8100
ans(:,:,1,8) = 0.7640
ans(:,:,1,9) = 0.8135
```

EDIT: For reference,

```
Size(A) = [200 200 4]
Size(L) = [200 200 4 9] 
Size(w) = [1 9]
```

EDIT: That's how I do it using loops

[image: loop]

Comment: To get a vector, try `squeeze(L(1,1,1,:))`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Multidimensional multiplication doesn't work in Matlab and that's why you can't do `A = L * w`*!

From Mathworks page ([How can I perform multi-dimensional matrix multiplication in MATLAB?](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-171X2/index.html?product=ML&solution=1-171X2)):

> Solution:
>
> The ability to perform multi-dimensional matrix multiplication in
>   MATLAB is not available.
>
> As a workaround, use a FOR loop.
>
> In addition, there is a user created function called NDFUN than
>   performs N-D matrix multiplication. For more information, see the
>   section on NDFUN at the following URL:
>
> http://www.mit.edu/~pwb/matlab/

Solution with loops should look like this:

```
A = zeros( size(L)(1:3) );
for i = 1:size(L,1)
    for j = 1 : size(L,2)
        A(i,j,:) = squeeze( L(i,j,:,:) ) * w';
    end
end
```

---

But if you would prefer concise solution over the faster one (looping should be fast), you could use approach from answer [Multiply a 3D matrix with a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745299/multiply-a-3d-matrix-with-a-2d-matrix) (assuming `size(L) == [200 200 4 9]` and `size(w) = [1 9]`):

```
Ac = cellfun( @(x) squeeze(x)' * w', num2cell(L,4), 'UniformOutput', false);
A = cell2mat( squeeze(Ac) );
```

Comment: yes A is x*y*4. I cannot simply do A=L*w 'I get Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.' Size(A) = [200 200 4], Size(L) = [200 200 4 9] Size(w) = [1 9]

Comment: You have to transpose `w` then and do the multiplication... `A = L * w'`

Comment: Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar

Answer (score 2):

Rather than using matrix multiplication with reshape, etc, in a double for loop, it might be better to reverse the process and loop over the shorter dimensions, like this:

```
A=zeros(size(L)(1:3));
for i=1:9
    A(:,:,:)=A(:,:,:)+w(i).*L(:,:,:,i);
end
```

As a result, rather than doing 40000 loops through a double for loop, you do a total of 9 loops. And I suspect that Matlab's JITA will work on such a loop, too, to produce an even better result (I use octave, so I can't be certain - it's also not worth me doing any timing tests, as octave's timings wouldn't be valid for matlab).

It's also possible to do it purely in a vector form, by simply using vector indexing rather than matrix indexing. It works like this:

```
A=zeros(size(L)(1:3));
A(:)=reshape(L,numel(A),9)*w';
```

This version uses reshape, of course, but it avoids bsxfun and squeeze, and I suspect that it'll be faster than other solutions except the aforementioned for loop over the 9 values.

(naturally, if you want to restrict it to only the "First subpixel", you need to restrict the data. For the for loop option, just put a 1 in place of a colon in the appropriate places. For the reshape and matrix multiply option, replace L with L(:,:,1,:) in both places that it appears)

Answer (score 1):

you should use `squeeze` to get to a vector form. try

```
a=squeeze(L(1,1,1,:))
```

Comment: Thanks, squeeze works. But when I do A(:,:,1)= w*squeeze(L(:,:,1,:)), I still get 'Inputs must be 2-D, or at least one input must be scalar.'

Comment: the outcome of `squeeze(L(:,:,1,:))` will be a 3D matrix, not a vector or a 2D matrix since you are only keeping the 3rd dimension of L constant, the rest of the three dimensions will be squeezed into a 3D matrix. What exactly do you try to accomplish? what is `size(w)` ?

Comment: I just want to compute the result for the 1st sub-pixels for all (x,y) in one go. That why I guess it's something like  A(:,:,1)= w*L(:,:,1,:))

Answer (score 1):

I've recently become a big fan of `bsxfun` and, assuming I've understood you correctly, this seems like a perfect fit for it. We only need to reshape `w` and then take advantage of `bsxfun`'s ability to automatically expand singleton dimensions to make the sizes of its inputs match.

```
w = reshape(w, [1, 1, 1, length(w)]);
A = sum(bsxfun(@times, L, w), 4);
```