# Multiply vector with block matrix in matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix-multiplication

I have a matrix A with dimensions 15NxM. That is, it consists of N different 15xM matrixes stacked on top of each other.

I also have a vector B with dimension 1x15.

What I would really like to do is to perform simple matrix multiplication B*A(Block) on each of the N blocks in A, so that I end up with a NxM matrix.

I need to do this without making any loops, because the main reason I am doing this is to gain some speed.

Thanks.

Comment: Take a look at this stackoverflow [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745299/multiply-a-3d-matrix-with-a-2d-matrix).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try

```
result = reshape( B * reshape(A, 15, []), N, M);
```

This avoids ever creating the intermediate "repmat" copy of B; but `reshape` can be slow.

Answer (score 0):

You could convert your `A` matrix into a cell array. First you are going to want to create an N-element array of your matrix dimension (15) for specifying the sizes of your cells:

```ml
dimArray = repmat(15, 1, N);    % 1xN array of the number 15
```

Next you will call `mat2cell` on your matrix `A` to convert it into a cell array where each cell is a 15xM submatrix of A:

```ml
newA = mat2cell(A, dimArray);
```

Finally, call `cellfun` on the cell array to do your multiplication:

```ml
result = cellfun(@(x) B*x, newA, 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Which should give you a cell array `result` containing the result of `B*A(block)` for each block in your `A` matrix. You can probably put this all in one line, or at most two:

```ml
result = cellfun(@(x) B*x, mat2cell(A, repmat(15, 1, N)), 'UniformOutput', false);
```

Not the clearest code to read though. This seems like a somewhat round-about way of doing it. If somebody gets it to work with `repmat` or similar then that might be the better way to go.

Comment: Since `B` is a row vector, I don't think you need the transpose in your `(x) B.'*x` - I think correct form would start `cellfun(@(x)B*x`. When I tried this, I needed to set `uniformoutput` to `false`, then convert the resulting cell array. Seems unnecessarily complex?

Comment: Yeah, it does seem a little over-complicated. And I must have read the dimensions wrong for `B`, thanks for pointing that out. Changed now.

Comment: In what version of matlab don't you need the `@` before the `(x)`? That is the other error I tried to point out...

Comment: Oh, sorry, I totally missed the @. Updated accordingly.