# Multiplying a 3D Matrix with a 1D

Tags: matlab, vectorization

I attempted to use the solution from this post: [Multiply a 3D matrix with a 2D matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1745299/multiply-a-3d-matrix-with-a-2d-matrix), to vectorize the multiplication of a one dimensional with a three dimensional, but to no avail. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
for s = 1: s_length
   for a = 1: a_length
      for g = g_length
         two_dim(s,a) = two_dim(s,a) + one_dim(g) * three_dim(s,a,g); 
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: Post a small example with inputs and desired ouput

Comment: If I understand correctly, you have to initiallize `two_dim` to `zeros(s_length,a_length)`, and the third line should be `for g = 1:g_length`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this does what you want.

```
two_dim = reshape(three_dim, [], size(three_dim,3))*one_dim(:);
two_dim = reshape(two_dim, size(three_dim,1), size(three_dim,2));
```

This works as follows:

- First line reshapes your 3D array into a matrix, collapsing the first two dimensions into one. That way the operation you want is standard multiplication of the resulting matrix times a column vector.
- Second line reshapes the result into matrix shape.

Comment: This could be a simpler way to put it - `reshape(reshape(three_dim,[],g_length)*one_dim,s_length,[])`? Maybe not that easy to explain though.

Comment: @Divakar Yes... it's just that I wanted to get rid of those variables, to show they are not needed. But yes, if the OP needs those variables anyway, your version is easier to read

Answer (score 1):

`mtimes` does not work with inputs with dimension larger than 2, so you have to find a way to do the multiplication by yourself. The solution of Luis Mendo is a nice solution; here is another one using `bsxfun`:

```
two_dim = two_dim + squeeze(sum(bsxfun(@times, three_dim, reshape(one_dim,[1 1 g_length])),3));
```

Here is how it works:

- `reshape` makes the vector `one_dim` looking like a 3D array. This must be done because the multiplication between the vector and the 3D array is performed along the 3rd dimension, so Matlab need a hint on sizes.
- `bsxfun` perfoms the element-wise multiplcation, so the result must be sumed up along the 3rd dimension (and squeezed to be compliant with a 2D matrix format)

Comment: For the use of `bsxfun` ! +1

Comment: Would you mind correcting the parentheses? The parentheses aren't balanced.